# how to programmatically invalidate a session using spring security

Tags: session, spring-security, invalidation

Some users of my application can use it for a fixed maximum amount of time.  At the first request happening past the expiration time, after checking the user is part of the target group, I want to invalidate the session, update the user and return a 401.

In theory a servlet filter invoked post-session-validation could be used for this.  I am looking for pointers on how to do this using spring security.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by At the first request happening past the expiration time, after checking the user is part of the target group? What do you want to check here and what's happening after checking that in current scenario? Also, could you please help with your spring security config files and parts where you are checking that?

Comment: Here is what I would like to achieve: At every (authenticated) request, information associated with the principal is retrieved, used to determine whether this principal is subject to session expiration as described above (i.e. in target), and if so, check the age of the user and invalidate the session if the age exceeds the limit.

Comment: The app is not using any spring security config *files*.  Configuration is achieved programmatically using a WebSecurityConfigurer instance (see http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.0.M1/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/EnableWebSecurity.html).  I was hoping to be able to extend this configuration by specifying a handler/filter invoked on each request after session validation.  But I'm having a hard time finding relevant documentation.

Answer (score 0):

While you could most certainly just add a normal servlet filter that executes at the very end of the chain (or at least after the Spring Security filter stack) where you get the SecurityContext and inspect the user (potentially logging out the user like [this](http://chrisjordan.ca/post/15052400009/programatically-logging-a-user-out-in-spring) or [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#logout())), I would suggest you instead simply change the session duration on per-user basis. After a successful login (`AuthenticationSuccessHandler` is a good place) you could simply call `setMaxInactiveInterval` on the session and give it a different value depending on the user's role. This seems a lot cleaner to me as you don't have to separately handle otherwise semantically equal *actual* and *forced* session expiration/logout cases.

Comment: Thanks for the followup.  In this case I don't care whether the user is active or not.  I just want to be able to block users access after a certain amount of time.  I ended up implementing the check in a user resolution utility invoked by all controllers.